# Firefox preventDefault on mousemove doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, onmousemove

This simple piece of code works in Chromium but not in Firefox. Why, and what's the best way to disable page interaction while moving the mouse. I'm trying to implement drag and drop, and I want to disable interactions while dragging.

```js
$('body').on('mousemove', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Try to select this text.<br>
In Chromium, you can't, as expected.<br>
In Firefox, you can, as unexpected.
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zu0jpar2/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`selectstart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/selectstart_event) event.

```js
$('body').on('selectstart', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Try to select this text.<br>
In Chromium, you can't, as expected.<br>
In Firefox, you can, as unexpected.
```

Or CSS [`user-select`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select) property:

```css
body {
   user-select: none;
}
```

```html
Try to select this text.<br>
In Chromium, you can't, as expected.<br>
In Firefox, you can, as unexpected.
```

Comment: This works for this specific example, but it's specific to text selection, right? I want to block move events in general.